# Padding doesn't work on some devices

Tags: android, android-layout, padding, android-xml

I had a strange problems during the set padding to `EditText`. xml looks like this:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:hint="Or Use your Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/line_white"
    android:paddingLeft="16.5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp" />
```

Here is the screenshot from Samsung Note 2 (Android 5.0.1):

[image]

... and LG G3 (Android 4.4.2):

[image]

As you can see, `android:paddingLeft` doesn't work for LG.

What could be the reason?

Thanks.

---

**UPD:**
Layout bounds (LG):

[image]

Comment: It must work .. due to different dpi of devices padding varies.. try using a big value like 50 instead of 16.5dp to check if it works or not? Let me know if it works

Comment: @Salmaan The result is the same. Works fine on Samsung, but on LG parameter is ignored.

Comment: Go to developers options and check show layout bounds. Post your screenshot after that...

Comment: @Salmaan The post is updated.

Comment: PPI of note 2 is 265 where PPI of G3 is almost twice as note i.e.538 how much padding did you applied?

Comment: Just found out there is problem with API level 21. Do it programatically and it will work fine tv.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EditText padding via xml doesn't work after update to API level 21.
But EditText padding works, if it define programmatically.

```
editText.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
```

You can track this issue on [android issue tracker.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77982)

There are some other alternates too, discussed in the issue tracker thread.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed this on the HTC One X.  This doesn't fix your particular issue, but changing `paddingStart` to `paddingLeft` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is dpi device problem. Make use of "dimen" folder, give different dp for various device screen sizes. Sure this will solve your problem.

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/yourValueName"
```