# Android add a padding with size that looks equal on all devices

Tags: android, android-layout, padding, density-independent-pixel

I have a `view` that is the same size as my screen / fragment. However, I want to add a padding on the left and right edges such that on all devices, this padding looks like its the same size. when I use:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp">
....
```

The padding is not equal on all devices. On a tablet, it is much smaller than on a small phone. Is there a way maybe programmatically to set the padding as equal on all devices?

and is `dp` supposed to be density-independent? Then how come, on different density devices the padding set to `dp` is not always the same size visually?

Comment: Density independent != size independent. Use `layout_weight` for relative sizing

Answer (score 1):

Notice that what you want is not scalable and not recommended. The reason is that the sizes of devices vary a lot in Android, as well as their pixel densities.

Furthermore, I include a [more general article](https://javapapers.com/android/difference-between-dp-dip-sp-px-in-mm-pt-in-android/) that might help you.

However:

A. Try with other units like mm or in, which are "based on the physical size of the screen" ([see](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) documentation).

B. Maybe set it programmatically. That is, calculate how many px/etc. you need on each device so that it looks the same (mm) on all of them.

```
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Finally, I am not sure if this is the case, but as other users sugest, maybe [this](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) could help. Once again, however, I am not entirely sure if this is what you need. On the same line, you can also define sizes depending on the details of the device with qualificators (refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android)).

Answer (score 0):

You need manage different dimens file for different resolutions , please check this link , You just need to put your padings parameter in dimens and then use from dimens.

[How to define dimens.xml for every different screen size in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android)

Answer (score -1):

Like the answer said in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30092751/10482656)

on API 21 padding doesn't work via XML, you can define programmatically like the link i share above

but you can try create `style="@style/RootLayoutWithPadding"` use this in your view

and inside `styles.xml` add this

`<style name="RootLayoutWithPadding">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin</item>
    </style>`

for every padding you can fill the sizes you want inside `values.xml`

i hope it help you :)